# Unable to Send Email using smtp using C#

Tags: c#

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 587;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Timeout = 10000;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials =true;
//my email and pass
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "senderpass");

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", "receiver@gmail.com", "test", "test");
mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
//client.Send(mm);
try {
    client.Send(mm);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateCopyMessage():{0}", ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: hmm, an SMTP class with a default constructor but requires Runtime Credentials without [Initialization]. Looks like a faulty structure.

Comment: Please show what error you were getting as "unable to send email" is *not* an actual problem description or question.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code:-**

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;


// SMTP host.

     try
     {
     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
     client.Port = 587;
     client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
     client.EnableSsl = true;
     client.Timeout = 10000;
     client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
     client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Sender@gmail.com","SenderPassword");

     MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("Sender@gmail.com", "Receiver@gmail.com", "test", "test");
     mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
     mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
     client.Send(mm);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateCopyMessage():{0}",
         ex.ToString());
     }
```